How to generate unique symbols inside a module that can also be used for pattern names?
I am trying to write code inside module, which will generate general pattern. The problem is that the number of terms in the pattern depends on the the input. So I can not hard code the pattern inside the module, since I do not know how many terms is needed.
Here is an example.
rule = a1_.  x + a2_. x^2 + a3_. x^3  :> {a1, a2, a3}
p = 3*x + 4*x^2 + 99*x^3
p /. rule 

(* {3, 4, 99} *)

Now I want to automate the above in a module that I can call with any polynomial. The problem is generating the rule line inside the module.
I tried using Unique[] to generate all the an symbols, in a loop. But once I add _ next to it, it does not work any more.
Better to give MWE to show what happens.
foo[n_Integer/;n>0,x_Symbol]:=Module[{a,patt,m,rule},
  rule =First@Last@Reap@Do[
       a = Unique[];
       Print[a];
       patt= (a_. x) (*THe problem is here. It is not using the unique symbol*);
       Sow[patt],
    {m,1,n}
    ];

   rule     
]

When I call it foo[4, x] it gives
  $45
  $46
  $47
  $48
  {x a$5574_., x a$5574_., x a$5574_., x a$5574_.}

It used the original a module variable and not the Unique one. Also the order changes. I wrote down a$nn_. x and it generates x a$nn_. instead.
Next I tried changing the code to just do this in the loop
   patt= (Unique[]_. x);
   Sow[patt],

And now it gave
   {x $49 _., x $50 _., x $51 _., x $52 _.}

Which is not what is expected. I expected
   {$49_. x , $50_. x, $51_. x , $52_. x}

I also tried generating all the unique symbols I need in table and then use them, like this
foo[n_Integer/;n>0,x_Symbol]:=Module[{uniqueName,patt,m,rule},
  uniqueName=Table[Unique[],n];
  rule =First@Last@Reap@Do[
       patt= (uniqueName[[m]]_. x) 
       Sow[patt],
    {m,1,n}
    ];
   rule      
]

This gave similar thing
foo[4, x] // InputForm

{x*$77*(_.), x*$78*(_.), x*$79*(_.), x*$80*(_.)}

I do not know how to make it generate
{$77_. x, $78_. x, $79_. x, $80_. x}

i.e. how to correctly use Unique[] to generate names that can be used for pattern names.
V 14.1

rule = poly_?PolynomialQ :> Rest[CoefficientList[poly, x]];

@BobHanlon this was just an example. I need to build much more complicated rule for other things. I just picked polynomial here to make things simple. I need to be able to generate unique symbols and any rule using these symbols as pattern names with _ after them. I also need to add these symbols at the end using :>{a1,a2,....} and so on. So looking for a general way to do this not specific to just polynomial.

Well, this isn't related to Module, it's merely a matter of evaluation order. OK, evaluation order is advanced topic, so let me post an answer anyway.
Your foo fails just because, Pattern owns the attribute HoldFirst:
Attributes@Pattern

(* {HoldFirst, Protected} *)

So we need to adjust the evaluation order a bit, notice in this case we cannot the shorthand for Pattern and Optional. (a_. is short for Optional@Pattern[a, _]):
foo[n_Integer /; n > 0, x_Symbol] := 
 Module[{a, patt, m, rule}, 
  rule = First[
    Last[Reap[Do[a = Unique[]; Print[a]; 
                 patt = Optional@Pattern[Evaluate@a, _] x; 
       Sow[patt], {m, 1, n}]]]]; rule]


To generate the desired rule:
rulefoo[n_Integer /; n > 0, x_Symbol] := With[{uniqueName = Table[Unique[], n]},
  (Optional@Pattern[#, _] & /@ uniqueName) . x^Range[n] :> Evaluate@uniqueName]

rulefoo[4, x]
(* x $45_. + x^2 $46_. + x^3 $47_. + x^4 $48_. :> {$45, $46, $47, $48} *)


Thanks. I actually did try Evaluate and it did not work. I also just copied your first code above to my notebook and it also gave syntax error. I am using V 14.1 on windows. Clean kernel. WHich version are you using? Here is screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/nSU1gHjP.png   Is the first version you wrote supposed to work as is?  It gives Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "Evaluate[a]:_.)".  So you have two versions you show. Which one of these is the one I am supposed to use? :)

@Nasser Strange. Actually what I wrote is Optional@Pattern[Evaluate[a], _], I then change it to StandardForm with Ctrl+Shift+n, which looks reasonable at a glance so I don't check further. I didn't expect it's illegal!

No problem. I do not understand your second example. Too advanced for me. But the first one I understand and can use, except for the syntax error it would be really good solution.  May be you can find why it gives syntax error. I am not good at patterns :(

@Nasser I think it's a bug of the front-end. (It generates incorrect code when pressing Ctrl+Shift+n), will report to WRI. Now the code is revised, have a look :) .

THanks, You revised one works well. I would never have guessed I needed to use Optional@Pattern[Evaluate@a, _] x;

Do I misunderstand something, but it looks rather simple to get the coefficient and the exponent of x:
foo[pol_, x_Symbol] := Module[{c, poly},
  cs = Reap[
     pol /. a_  x^n_ :> (Sow[{a, n}];) /. (a_ : 1)  x :> Sow[{a, 1}];
     ][[2, 1]];
  SortBy[cs, Last]
  ]

foo[1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4  x^3 +  Sin[10 x^5], x]

{{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {10, 5}}


Well, as mentioned by Nasser in comment above, this is merely a toy example, the real case is not limited to polynomial.

Thanks, but I need to generate symbols for patterns using Unique, so I can use them later in :>{a1,a2,...}. I am trying to implement answer by xzczd here rule = (p1 : a_. x : 0) + (p2 : b_. y : 0) + (p3 : c_. y^2 : 0) :> {Plus@a, Plus@b, Plus@c};  but inside a module, where input can be any length and not just for polys. So I asked this question for just the first part, which is rule = (a_. x ) + (b_. y ) + (c_. y^2) and now I need to figure how to do the rest :(

i.e. the main idea is how to automatically generate ONLY the rule inside module using Unique names for patterns. The module will return back the rule to the caller. Then the caller will use this rule on their input.  I used polynomial as an example. i.e. I need to be able to eventually do (pnnn : ppnnn_. y^nnnn : 0)....:>{Plus@ppnnn,Plus@....} where ppnnn and pnnn are symbols generated on the fly inside the module. I will use this to generate rule to pick the coefficients of a differential equation for example, which can be of any order where some terms are missing in the ode.
